# Move an element to the end of arry and insert a new element at the free position with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the below html. I want to grab div2 move it after div4 (end of array) and insert a new div1.5 at the new free position.

```
   <div id="data">
      <div>1</div>  
      <div>2</div>    
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
```

I am sure this can be done with a one or twoliner. But how?

Comment: Explore jquery draggable solution

Comment: No I want to do it programmatically not drag it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `eq()` to select the second div, `replaceWith` to change it's content, and `appendTo()` to add it back to the end of the parent `div`. Try this:

```
var $div2 = $('#data div').eq(1);
var $newDiv = $('<div />', { text: '1.5' });
$div2.replaceWith($newDiv).appendTo('#data');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nbLxnj97/)

Alternatively, you can just change the text of the second `div`, and add a 'new' div 2 to the end:

```
$('#data div').eq(1).text('1.5');
$('<div />', { text: '2' }).appendTo('#data');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nbLxnj97/1/)

Comment: can you change your fiddle to NOT use hardcoded value 1 or any text 1.5 hacks :-)

Comment: What do you mean? They're not 'hacks'. Just change those values to use whatever variables you have...?

Comment: When I mean hardcoded value than I mean please refer to the index of the element list not the string value inside :-)

Comment: That's what it's doing - `eq(1)` refers to the second element by index.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what's the background of your question, but you one solution can be the following example:

```js
$('#data div:eq(1)').insertAfter('#data div:eq(3)');
$('<div>1.5</div>').insertAfter('#data div:eq(0)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```